# TextureRegion cuts texture in a wrong way

Tags: graphics, libgdx, game-engine

I want to have a background texture with 3 rectangles and i want to create animation with them, - [texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8wp3.jpg)

But first rectangle cuts in a proper way and two others are cut in a dumb way
    [Proper way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pays5.png),
    [Dumb way #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pays5.png#1),
    [Dumb way #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pays5.png#2)

Here is my code.

```
    public class MainMenu implements Screen{

    Texture background_main;
    TextureRegion[] background_textures;
    Animation background_animation;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    TextureRegion current_frame; 
    float stateTime;
    BobDestroyer game;
    OrthographicCamera camera;

    public MainMenu(BobDestroyer game){
       this.game = game;
}

    @Override
    public void show() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(true, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        background_main = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("main_menu_screen/Background.png"));
        background_textures = new TextureRegion[3];

        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            background_textures[i] = new TextureRegion(background_main,0, 0+72*i, 128, 72+72*i);
        }
        background_animation = new Animation(2f,background_textures);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); 
        current_frame = background_animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
        batch.begin(); 
        batch.draw(current_frame,0, 0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());    
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, are you trying to create 3 TextureRegions of the same width/height? If yes, your issue may be with:

```
new TextureRegion(background_main,0, 0+72*i, 128, 72+72*i)
```

I think you'd want:

```
new TextureRegion(background_main,0, 0+72*i, 128, 72)
```

As the 128x72 is the width/height (not x/y positions) of your next TextureRegions, and do you not want them all the same height (72) as opposed to varying heights (72+72*i)?